# Rascal: Grammar to Parse BNF

Tags: grammar, rascal

I want to write a concrete grammar to parse BNF-like syntax definitions.

Looking at the [EXP Concrete Syntax](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Recipes/Recipes.html#/Recipes/Languages/Exp/Concrete/NoLayout/NoLayout.html) recipe I created this very simple first version:

```
module BNFParser

lexical Identifier = [a-z]+ ;

syntax GrammarRule = left RuleHead ":" RuleCase* ";" ;
syntax RuleHead = Identifier ;
syntax RuleCase =  Identifier ;
```

and invoked it in the Repl like this:

```
import BNFParser;
import ParseTree;
parse(#GrammarRule, "foo : bar baz ;");
```

But this results in a rather arcane error message:

```
|std:///ParseTree.rsc|(13035,1963,<393,0>,<439,114>): ParseError(|unknown:///|(3,1,<1,3>,<1,4>))
        at *** somewhere ***(|std:///ParseTree.rsc|(13035,1963,<393,0>,<439,114>))
        at parse(|std:///ParseTree.rsc|(14991,5,<439,107>,<439,112>))
ok
```

I also tried using the `start` keyword ahead of GrammarRule, but that didn't help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Thomas; you're perhaps missing a layout definition for the whitespace and comments in between all the rest?

Comment: Great, thanks for the quick responses. That helped. I still get an `Ambiquity` error on the Kleene star `RuleCase*`. Same with `+`. Leaving both away I can parse `foo : bar;` ok.

Comment: Just never nest a * list in a + list directly, that results in cyclic rules (and thus also ambiguous). Also, for lists of identifiers you need to declare longest match by adding `!>> [a-z]` to the end of the Identifier lexical rule. It says that the rule should not reduce unless there is no more a's to z's to consume. Rascal does no heuristic or implicit disambiguation like other parser/lexer generators do. You've to declare it all, but then you know exactly what you're dealing with 

Comment: Yep, thanks Jurgen, that fixed it. I just came across the same hint in the `SyntaxDefinition` concept page :-) . - Go ahead and make a 2-line answer, so I can upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lexical Identifier = [a-z]+ !>> [a-z];
```

That helps for ambiguous lists of identifiers. The additional !>> constraint declares that identifiers are only acceptable if no further characters can be consumed.

Also this is required for fixing the parse error:

```
layout Whitespace = [\ \n\r]*;
```

For all syntax rules in scope it will intermix this nonterminal between all symbols. It leaves the lexical rules alone.

Comment: What really strikes me is that - if I get it right - in the `eval` function of the EXP recipe you are using _tree pattern matching_ on the parse tree to distinguish the function clauses ... wow.

Comment:  I love that too about Rascal; although the concrete tree pattern match and construction features could use some more love to get it to the level of usability of Rascal's predecessor (ASF+SDF). We're working on something else now first, which is the Rascal static checker and Compiler. Stay tuned!